# Mic Blue Yeti not recognized after Lock

Tags: sound, suspend, pulseaudio, microphone, services

I'm having an issue: when my Ubuntu 20.4 returns from Lock or Suspend, the Blue Yeti microphone is not being recognized. I am wondering if there is a way to refresh the audio/USB via restart service so that I can refresh the audio properties via command line.

Something like:

```
sudo restart audio.service
```

Is that possible ?

Edit: note that I do not want to reconnect the USB every time the computer returns from Lock.

Comment: Simply reconnecting should do it. And you should look for and install an UEFI update because that's an hardware initialization issue (managed by UEFI or BIOS) most of the times.

Comment: That's something I don't want to do, reconnect the USB every time my computer locks.